# Request Timeout Server is not responding

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, timeout

I have a project in that I am calling a stored procedure to retrieved  data from database but when I am running that stored procedure through UI it giving above mentioned error.

Exception Details: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out

my stack trace are:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +2444082
>          System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>   +5775560
>          System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +285
>          System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +4169
>          System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData() +58
>          System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData() +89
>          System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds,
>   RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean
>   isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption) +409
>          System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
>   async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry,
>   SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest) +2127
>          System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task,
>   Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry) +911
>          System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method) +64
>          System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method) +240
>          System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior) +41
>          System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader() +14
>          System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.Execute(Expression query, QueryInfo queryInfo, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[]
>   parentArgs, Object[] userArgs, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries, Object
>   lastResult) +1290
>          System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.ExecuteAll(Expression query, QueryInfo[] queryInfos, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[]
>   userArguments, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries) +118
>          System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression
>   query) +342
>          System.Data.Linq.DataContext.ExecuteMethodCall(Object instance, MethodInfo methodInfo, Object[] parameters) +83
>
> ```
>    myclass file(Boolean IsActive, String role, Int64 userID, Int64 InstID, String deptID) in 
>    System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +51
>    System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +95
>    System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +59
>    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
> ```
>
> +678

when I execute same stored procedure in my database it giving me data as a result but through UI it is not going to next page and loading the result.

Comment: please add exception message, not only stack trace.

Comment: Exception Details: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out.
this is the exception details

Comment: check for `Connection Timeout` in your connection string

Comment: ya my connection timeout I set to 500sec and  as my query needs only 45 sec to execute in database.

Comment: are you having issue only for this particular SP call? Check if there can be an issue with Db connectivity?